Subtracting a glacier thickness raster layer from a DEM layer
I have two raster layers:

One contains multiple polygons showing the thickness of glaciers, and the
Second one being a DEM layer of the area (including the glaciers).

I am trying to subtract the thickness of the glaciers from the DEM layer so I can get a DEM of the area without glaciers present.
I have tried using the Raster Calculator to just subtract one from the other, then the Warp (Reproject) function to match the layer extents of the smaller ice thickness polygon layer and both times the output layer only contained the polygons, not the whole extents of the DEM layer.
How do I go about subtracting the glacier thickness layer from the DEM, keeping the extents of the DEM?
I am using the 3.34.9 QGIS version, I've tried to subtract the two layers both in the .tif and .map formats.

See here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/456134/88814

Try the following steps an be sure that your two inputs have the same CRS:

rasterize your polygone layer with gdal:rasterize processing tool. For the output extent choose the extent of your DEM Layer!



Run grass7:rnull processing tool and set NULL values to 0 to your polygon-raster
Make the difference between DEM and polygon-raster with the raster calculator

